# How to correctly import a Python library into a Django project (hosted on Heroku)?

Tags: python, django, api, heroku, recurly

I need to include the Recurly API library into a Django project. 
The library is on GitHub, and the project is deployed to Heroku.
Currently, I have the following added to requirements.txt:

```
-e git://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-python.git#egg=recurly-client-python
```

This may work once the app is on heroku (?) but it's not getting picked up when developing locally (running local server via foreman). In my test app's views.py, I have:

```
import recurly
```

I get:

```
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named recurly
Exception Location: /Users/pete/Documents/code/django/simpleblog/subscriptions/views.py in <module>, line 7
Python Executable:  /Users/pete/.virtualenvs/django/bin/python
```

I'm pretty new to Django/Python, as well as working with APIs in this environment. How should I install & include it, so it works both locally and once deployed? I tried searching online to no avail.

Comment: did you run `pip install -r requirements.txt` _after_ adding it ?

Comment: Another thing. in `requirements.txt`, you can just do `recurly == 2.1.1` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First method:

What you can do is clone the code on your desktop :

> git clone https://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-python.git

and then from this new directory run

> python setup.py install

(This is how you can install any reusable python app into your environment)

EDIT1:

Second method:
simply change requirement.txt

"-e git://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-python.git#egg=recurly-client-python" to "recurly"

If you are new to python and want easy and fast implementation use second one. If you are new to python and want to learn how things work in python use first one, it will help.

EDIT2:

Wanna learn more? Check which version you got installed by these two different methods. ("pip list|grep recurly")

Comment: Karthik's answer above was what I needed to make this particular API to work (locally). But just curious, what is the difference between including an API in requirements.txt, vs installing it manually per your answer above? (Also, assuming I'd be running the install from within the project's active virtualenv?)

Comment: You are right, should be running that from within active virtualenv.

Comment: Let's get one step back and understand this concept. When somebody makes a python package he can distribute it to others by giving them code away and let them run "python setup.py install" or he can push to repository called "PyPi". pip is a tool that can easily install easily from that repository using command "pip install <packagename>", requirement.txt is a shortcut to install multiple packages by "pip install -r requirement.txt" where requirement.txt contains all packages name. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip